# iBook Private Distribution

Tags: distribution, ibooks

I'm just getting started with apples new iBook Publishing tools and I'm wondering if there is any way you can privately distribute an exported iBook through a link. I'm think there might be a way to do this that is similar to the way you can share an iOS app with a Enterprise or Ad-Hoc distribution certificate?

I know that you can send it via e-mail, but in the case that the iBook is larger than 10-20mb it will probably get blocked by managed email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late response. You can take the .ibooks file and write it to some webserver location to be picked up by your users. The ideal way would be to serve it up through an MDM server, however from my experience iBooks is a fairly new technology and our current MDM isn't looking for .ibooks files.. only .ipa. I imagine that will change in newer releases.

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience, you can only do ad-hoc distribution of unregistered books (those without an ISBN, and other formalities) by using the 'Preview' option in iBooks Author.

It would be great to have OTA distribution for the files, but I have been unable to figure out a way to do so for my small business.

Comment: What is OTA? I don't seem to find it...

Comment: Over the Air Distribution. Means to download or obtain a file, or simply transfer data, without syncing to a particular device via a cable or docking mechanism.